Yii2 Active Record Order By Primary Key ID not working
I have a pretty basic Yii2 ActiveRecord query.
$paperList = Paper::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->all();

id is my primary key column which is of type int and AUTO_INCREMENT.
When running the simple select * from paper order by id desc directly on MySQL it works perfectly and I get a list such as: 18,17,16
But when running the Yii2 code above, it keeps the order as 16,17,18
On a larger table it also seems to be sorting weird. It will return: 100, 101, 102, 20, 21
But should be returning: 102, 101, 100, 21, 20
If I use Query Builder with standard SQL in my code, then it's not an ActiveRecord anymore.

Your code looks correct.
AFAIK possible issues:

Conflicting logic or scopes, if you have defined custom scopes or filters in your model, they might override the orderBy clause.

Query caching - if query caching is enabled, the results might be coming from the cache, not reflecting the correct order.


Try this approach - if you're using a GridView or similar data presentation, use an ActiveDataProvider to manage the query:
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Paper::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]),
]);

If it doesn't help try to check the debug toolbar to confirm that the generated SQL query includes the ORDER BY clause.

Thank you Mikhail. Although your answer did not directly help me, it did point me in the right direction of checking my other models. From my Paper object I am also getting info from other linked tables, such as Author and Category. On my view side when I remove all of that and print just the Paper id's then the orderby works. So clearly something on one of the linked tables is causing this. I will investigate further. Cheers.
